# Regular Expressions in Razor: The type or namespace name 'Match' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am doing a Razor page. The following is the beginning of this cshtml file:

```
@{
    var year = Request.QueryString["year"];

    Match match = Regex.Match(year, @"^\d\d\d\d$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

When loading the page, I got the following error:

> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Match'
>   could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)
>
> Source Error:

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Are you missing a `using` directive? (look at what the error message is telling you)

Comment: do you have a `using` directive for `System.Text.RegularExpressions` ?

Comment: if this is `MVC` you can also add `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace to your `Web.config` file under the `Views` folder

Comment: @Savanna: The accepted answer on that question isn't even in the ballpark.  Despite the title, that question appears to be a highly-localized troubleshooting problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this to the top of your file:

```
@using System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `@using System.Text.RegularExpressions` ad the top of your template.